# OneDrive not syncing after remote file changes

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive

OneDrive shows as "up to date" and won't sync anything modified remotely until restarted or until any local modifications are made. Then it scans and updates remote changes.
I'm suspecting WNS issues, but have no idea how to debug.

Comment: What kind of remote modification is it? From web interface or other OneDrive client?

Comment: Tried both from web version and uploading stuff from an Android client.